# Downgrade GnuPG using brew

Tags: macos, gnupg, homebrew

I need to downgrade GnuPG in my system, so what I did was to first uninstall it:

```
brew uninstall gnupg
```

it uninstalled successfully (apparently)

Then I tried to install again the needed version:

```
brew install gnupg@2.2
```

but I get the following error:

```
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to ghcr.io port 443: Operation timed out
    Error: gnupg@2.2: Failed to download resource "libnghttp2_bottle_manifest"
    Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libnghttp2/manifests/1.46.0
```

I'm sure I'm not using any proxy, any idea what could be happening?

**NOTE**

I of course made sure that

```
brew doctor
```

and

```
brew update
```

are fine, there's nothing wrong with brew aparently.